# detached entity passed to persist in one-to-one relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, one-to-one

I try to create a new child entity Card. I want to attach a User(parent entity) to a new card. But I get a log with the following message:

> detached entity passed to persist: com.example.gig_hunt.model.entity.User

Parent entity User:

```
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long userId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Card card; }
```

Child class Card:

```
public class Card {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long cardId;

@OneToOne
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user; }
```

Postman:

> {
> "cardNumber" : 62778948348,
> "cvv" : 652,
> "holderName" : "snbhbdhjrjm",
> "validTo" : "2025-10-15",
> "user" : {
> "userId" : 3
> }
> }

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code of the service where you are saving entities. But one thing seems to be wrong in the Card entity class: `@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long cardId;` Shouldn't be `"card_id"`?